# How to Get Pod Termination time using metric?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus, metrics

I want to find termination date of pods Im using

```
kube_pod_created
```

to get creation time

but I can't find how to get end time I found this metric but its not working for me

```
kube_completion_time
```

it return empty result and in specific range time it return two pods

```
{pod="kube-state-second-metrics-6c69cbc46b-wdxqk"}
{pod="vpnkit-controller"}
```

Im stuck with this for week can't figure it out

Comment: Try `kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Succeeded"}`. It will return a list of pods that have successfully completed, along with their termination timestamps. Each pod in the result will have a `kube_pod_status_phase` metric value of `Succeeded` and the corresponding `kube_pod_end_time` metric indicating the termination time.

Comment: I tried it i got this result 
I can't see the end time of pod it give the phase Succeeded that's correct but not the time

Comment: You can get timestamp of any metric with function [`timestamp()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#timestamp). I'm not sure how it will be done with pods, but to take time of last presence of metric my_metric, for example,  you can do `last_over_time(timestamp(my_metric)[1w:])`.

Comment: I executed time() and I notice that there is a delay by 1 hour I think this causing the problem do you know how to adjust the timezone in prometheus config file ?